# push new value to mongodb inner array - mongodb/php

Tags: php, mongodb

i have this document in mongo:

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("4d0b9c7a8b012fe287547157"),
   "done_by": ["1"]
}
```

and i want to add another value to "done_by" field, so my expected document will be::

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("4d0b9c7a8b012fe287547157"),
   "done_by": ["1","2","3"]
}
```

i try this:

```
$conn = new Mongo();
$q = $conn->server->gameQueue;
$id = new MongoId("4d0b9c7a8b012fe287547157");
$q->update(array("_id"=>$id),array('$push' => array("done_by","2")));
```

but nothing happens, anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Since neither of these answers are actually telling you what's wrong here ...

```
$conn = new Mongo();
$q = $conn->server->gameQueue;
$id = new MongoId("4d0b9c7a8b012fe287547157");
$q->update(array("_id"=>$id),array('$push' => array("done_by","2")));
```

There is a problem with your **$push** statement, you are not pushing "done_by" with a value of "2" you are actually sending "done_by" **and** "2" ...

Here is the issue ...

```
array('$push' => array("done_by","2"))
```

This should have a **=>** not a **,**

```
array('$push' => array("done_by" => "2"))
```

However, note that every time you run this it will insert another "2" if you want MongoDB to only inset "2" if it doesn't already exist in "done_by" then you should use **$addToSet** ...

```
array('$addToSet' => array("done_by" => "2"))
```

This statement won't add 2 everytime, only the first time.

Answer (score 4):

```
$filter = array('_id'=>$id));
$update = array('$push'=>array('done_by'=>'2'));
$q->update($filter,$update);
```

Answer (score 2):

`$push => array('done_by' => '2')`

So says the [manual](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%24push): `{ $push : { field : value } }`

Answer (score 0):

```
$filter = array('_id'=>$id));
$update = array('$addToSet'=>array('done_by'=>'2'));
$q->update($filter,$update);
```

When you need to update use `$addToSet` so you avoid duplicate inserts which leads to multiple entries.

Answer (score -1):

u can use as this :

```
$conn = new Mongo();
$q = $conn->server->gameQueue;
$id = new MongoId("4d0b9c7a8b012fe287547157");
$q->update(array("_id"=>$id),array('$addToSet' => array("done_by","2")));
```