# MongoDB - Saved into nested arrays from multiple pages without overwriting data

Tags: php, mongodb, database

New to MongoDB and trying to save data from multiple pages into the same nested array without overwriting. I will explain after the code the issue.

The desired document setup would like the following:

```
Array
(
    [15] => Array
        (
            [page1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => name
                    [quality] => 15
                    [price] => 200
                )

            [page2] => Array
                (
                    [name] => name
                    [quality] => 15
                    [price] => 200
                )

        )

    [_id] => MongoId Object
        (
            [$id] => 532d29f89d994909059b5e3b
        )
)
```

My update script per each page looks like this:

```
$collection->update(
    array( '_id' => new MongoId($docID) ),
    array( '$set' => array( $teamID => array( $page => $object )) )
  );
}
```

Just to add clarity, `15 = $teamID` and `page1 = $page` and the `[name],[quality] and [price]` plus their values are equal to `$object`.

Just incase it's important, the `$object` is build as follows:

```
$object = new stdClass();
  foreach ($_POST as $name => $value)
  {
    $object->$name = $value;
  }
```

The issue is that when I save from each page, instead of `page1` saving independently of `page2`, `page2` overwrites `page1`.

Let me know if there is more information that is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [`$push`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) operator or [`$addToSet`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) operator in your update statement instead of $set.

**$push** appends the element to the array and **$addToSet** appends to the array, if the element is not already present.

Comment: When I simply change out `$set` to `$addToSet` it doesn't work. I'm probably missing something in syntax. Can you provide an example using my code.

Comment: I wish I could help, but I'm not familiar with PHP syntax.  You could look at [`this link`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638368/push-new-value-to-mongodb-inner-array-mongodb-php)