# push new value to mongodb not work multi-process in php

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm coding a testing program: 
**200 processes write 10000 records to one collection in mongodb**
The record should be appended to the end of the collection, so I follow the example [[push new value to mongodb inner array][1] - mongodb/php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638368/push-new-value-to-mongodb-inner-array-mongodb-php)

below is my code:

```
$data = $memcache->get('data');
$m = new MongoClient();
$db = $m->record_test;
$collection = $db->record;
$time = $db->record_time;

for ($i=0; $i < 10000; $i++) { 
    $time_start = microtime_float();

    $collection->insert($data);

    $time_end = microtime_float();
    $run_time = $time_end - $time_start;

    $newdata = array('$push' => array('time' => $run_time));
    $time->update(array("time" => 0 ), $newdata);
}
```

$data's content:
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Register_Name] => MGC_IP
            [Register_Value] => 192.168.1.9
            [Register_Unit] => 
            [Device_Name] => this
            [R_W] => 
        )

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [Register_Name] => MGC_SW_VERSION
        [Register_Value] => 0.9.15.1022_SPI  
        [Register_Unit] =>  
        [Device_Name] => this
        [R_W] =>  R
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [Register_Name] => MGC_FW_VERSION
        [Register_Value] => 0.1.15.915.1     
        [Register_Unit] =>  
        [Device_Name] => this
        [R_W] =>  R
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [Register_Name] => MGC_ZONE_ID
        [Register_Value] => zone0    
        [Register_Unit] =>  
        [Device_Name] => this
        [R_W] =>  R
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [Register_Name] => MGC_DEVICE_ID
        [Register_Value] => mgc0     
        [Register_Unit] =>  
        [Device_Name] => this
        [R_W] =>  R
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [Register_Name] => MGC_SYS_TIME
        [Register_Value] => 2015/10/27 10:12:04  
        [Register_Unit] =>  
        [Device_Name] => this
        [R_W] =>  R
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [Register_Name] => MGC_P1_STATUS
        [Register_Value] => Access fails     
        [Register_Unit] =>  
        [Device_Name] => this
        [R_W] =>  R
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [Register_Name] => MGC_P2_STATUS
        [Register_Value] => Not configured   
        [Register_Unit] =>  
        [Device_Name] => this
        [R_W] =>  R
    )
```

)

After 10000 records has be done, I got nothing in the collection! I used this sample code to check my result:

```
$m = new MongoClient();
echo "Connection to database successfully.<br>";
$db = $m->record_test;
echo "Database record_test selected.<br>";
$time = $db->record_time;
echo "Collection record selected succsessfully.<br>";
echo $time->count(), "\n";

$cursor = $time->find();
var_dump(iterator_to_array($cursor));
```

Output:

```
Connection to database successfully.
Database record_test selected.
Collection record selected succsessfully.
0
```

Could someone help me? Why my var_dump() nothing? I'm really new in mongodb and PHP :'(

Comment: If you have multi-threaded inserts by spinning up new PHP processes what in the world makes you think they should be in order? As for your code, I see no `$data` defined, also what's the updte but no upsert about?

Comment: Plus your `$id` is not even defined which means your error reporting is too low to see errors

Comment: Thanks, I miss them when copy. Records don't  need to be in order, but ..They shall be in the same collection, isn't it? Or I misunderstand something?

Comment: They will be in the same collection but not in any order or an any set position

Comment: Why I  got nothing :'(   Is there anything wrong?

Comment: Are you sure `$data` is anything, can you print an example?

Comment: Also turn up your error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php to E_ALL

Comment: I print_r($data), it's a json type record as show in the question. And I report E_ALL, it seems show nothing more.

Comment: try to debugging par replace memcache item's value by  a single row fixed array value and check what you got in collection