# mongodb update/upsert that adds data to the existing document instead of replacing data in an existing document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, jenssegers-mongodb

I am using an upsert using mongodb's Jensseger PHP library.  Every time I add new data to the document it updates the value of the field if the field names are the same. I want to add to the document's data instead of replacing it.

An example of a record in my session_activities collection:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("622f8da565fbcea0a1b4ed12"),
"activity" : [
                {
                        "name" : "Fullscreen Off",
                        "time" : 219.972769,
                        "value" : 0
                },
                {
                        "name" : "Player Resize",
                        "time" : 220.074389,
                        "value" : 354
                },
                {
                        "name" : "close",
                        "time" : 223.779885,
                        "value" : 369
                }
        ]
```

If that record has a new "Player Resize" event at 500 seconds I want the document to change to:

```
  "_id" : ObjectId("622f8da565fbcea0a1b4ed12"),
        "activity" : [
                        {
                                "name" : "Fullscreen Off",
                                "time" : 219.972769,
                                "value" : 0
                        },
                        {
                                "name" : "Player Resize",
                                "time" : 220.074389,
                                "value" : 354
                        },{
                                "name" : "Player Resize",
                                "time" : 500,
                                "value" : 354
                        },
    
                        {
                                "name" : "close",
                                "time" : 223.779885,
                                "value" : 369
                        }
                ]
```

Right now the Player Resize field is being overwritten with the new value. My mongo statement looks like the below:

```
(new VideoAnalytics)->where($whereStatement)->update($this->newobj, ['upsert' => true])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you give the entire object with the key values you provided into the MongoDB update method it will replace the whole record, instead of that please start using `$set` in MongoDB to set the specific keys. Here also I'm adding a reference link for better understanding.

https://php.uz/manual/en/mongocollection.update.php

```
new VideoAnalytics->update(
    $whereStatement,
    array('$set' => $this->newobj),
    array('upsert' => true)
);
```

Comment: I don't want to replace the data. I want  to add to it.

Comment: yes, that's where you can start using $set, please refer to the link I added in the answer

Comment: It says " The dollar ($) prefixed field '$addToSet' in '$addToSet' is not valid for storage"

Comment: why your using $addToSet in update, $addToSet is the method using to add a new key while using aggregation function

Answer (score 0):

as I understand, you wanna update by pushing a new element to the array, right?

this might help [push new value to mongodb inner array - mongodb/php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638368/push-new-value-to-mongodb-inner-array-mongodb-php)